# Save entries to accdb on button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a WinForms application in C# with two forms:

**Form1**

[image]

**Form 2**

[image]

How would I save the contents to my data source when the user clicks on the save button e.g.

```
public Form2(string cell1, string cell2)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     textBox1.Text = cell1;
     textBox2.Text = cell2;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // save to access database when user clicks on the save button
}
```

i.e. run an SQL query as the following

```
UPDATE Table1
SET ID=value1,Team=value2,...
WHERE ID=value3;
```

Where:

> - value1 is the new ID
> - value2 is the new Team
> - value3 is the old ID (pulled from public Form2)

In a case where value1/value3 don't match - a new entry should be made in the Access database (i.e. an INSERT QUERY instead of an UPDATE query).

Would really appreciate some assistance on updating/inserting new rows into the Access database.

Comment: how did you load the entities?

Comment: after saving the new entry you will have to requery the db for the datagrid to show the new entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OleDB to access mdb, then something like:

```
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=blablabla"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                // prepare command
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 (id, team, old) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", connection);
                command.Parameters.Add("id", typeID).Value = newID;
                command.Parameters.Add("team", typeTeam).Value = team;
                command.Parameters.Add("old", typeOld).Value = oldID;
                // add new record
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here you have to have already `newID`, `team` and `oldID` values. I didn't specify types (typeID, typeTeam and typeOld).

To take `oldID` value you can pass it to an edit form as a parameter if that's a problem. I'll refine my answer if necessary, just say what is unclear.

Answer (score -2):

You can use static variable concept for this. **With the help of static variables you can pass value from one form to another**. Hence both of your string you can pass and then you can use queries for Insert or Update.

Comment: Database is obviously can be accessed from either of the form. OP is not asking about how to pass data between forms, but how to actually use specified technology (MS Access mdb-file).